# Excel Formula - If this then that - average over a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Hope I explain this well!

I have a spreadsheet where each worksheet contains raw data for a different company, with each sheet having exactly the same fields and layout. Each column in each worksheet has a drop-down for employee name, and the rest of the column is data gathered about an individual task that employee has performed, including a %score for that task.

On a Summary tab I would like to make a table for Employee Average Scores, pulling scores for each individual employee from their respective company worksheet into one place, so we can see the bigger picture and compare how everyone is scoring and easily identify those requiring further training.

Can a formula tell me:

'pulling from 'Company A' worksheet, give me the average %score from the 'Score' row E29 to CZ29, but only use scores where 'Employee Name' is also in the same column (The 'Employee Name' row runs between E8 and CZ8)?

Hope you can help! I'm learning Excel formulas at the moment but this is further than my skills can work out!

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample data and requested result

Comment: Welcome to SO. Probably, you could use SUM.IF to sum only those % using Employee Name as criteria, and then, divide that sum by COUNT.IF using Employee Name as criteria.

Comment: Or you could use [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this function:

B = Searching value row (employee list row)

H= Matching Value (employee name)

A= Score row

`=AVERAGEIF(B2:B7,H2,A2:A7)`